# https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js shows

Tags: javascript

Appreciate help: 
When searching for posts or pages in admin on website I get errors:
Error: You are sending a non-standard event 'Enrichment' - plus 5x this error: https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js

Thanks Michi

Comment: What is `admin`? Which `website`? Are you sure you don't need to ask your web administrator these questions? Or the developers of your platform? This sounds like an error thrown by internal software.

Comment: thank you and sorry for late reply. Admin: on my wordpress site when I search for pages or posts then I get this errors https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js

Comment: I have no pixel on the website either

Comment: I have checked all plugins and only got Shariff for social. maybe you know of somebody that could help me

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to be able to leave a "comment" on Stack, but apparently you need more reputation to do that. Anyway, here's some more information about this for the OP, and those assisting them.

I started seeing this issue in the last few days on a few websites. I also noticed that it seems isolated to Chrome specifically.  It'll happen on search boxes in the WordPress admin area's plugin search tool, or even on the front-end in a search box.

Unfortunately, the error references a page that is offline for maintenance, making it difficult to dive deeper into; https://www.facebookmarketingdevelopers.com/pixels/up#sec-custom